# The Data is not sorting even if used sort method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

The Data is not sorting even if used sort method
Every Time i refresh my page the data coming form mongodb is changes(I mean every time i fecth data from mongodb the indexes of data changes) I also used the sort method but did not worked

```js
app.get('/ot1', async(req, res)=>{
    
    const b = await dModel.aggregate([
        {
                    $match:{
                        bloodgroup:{
                            $in:["A+",  "B+",  "O+", "AB+",  "A-",  "B-",  "O-", "AB-"]         
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    $group:{
                        _id:
                            "$bloodgroup",
                        total:{
                            $sum: "$ml"
                        }
                    }
                },
                { "$sort": { "bloodgroup": 1 } },
             
    ]);
    console.log(b);
    console.log("-----------------");
```

Comment: Please prove any possible solution so show data in ejs templet with specific data / data index. So every time i refresh page, the data should not be changed

Comment: After your `"$group"` stage, field `"bloodgroup"` doesn't exist so the following `"$sort"` won't do what you want.  Maybe after the `"$group"` stage you want to sort on `"_id"`?  Or perhaps `"$set"`/`"$addFields"`/`"$project"` after the `"$group"` stage to reassign `"bloodgroup"` to `"_id"`?

Comment: "$bloodgrop" after the $group stage provide this data from database                          
  { _id: 'A+', total: 30 },
  { _id: 'B+', total: 70 },
  { _id: 'AB+', total: 20 },
  { _id: 'O+', total: 50 }   And Want to sort that data in ascending order(A-Z) so i can display data properly in ejs templet like(i have A+, B+, AB+) like this

Comment: After your `"$group"` stage, only the fields `"_id"` and `"total"` exist.  Which field(s) do you want to sort on?

Comment: So perhaps you want `{"$sort": {"_id": 1}}`?

Comment: I want to sort the Blood group field.. after sorting I want to total of particular data like total of A+, total of B+ individually

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me the exact output format you want, but here's one way to get the info you want and `"$sort"` by `"bloodgroup"`.

```js
db.bloodbank.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "bloodgroup": {
        "$in": ["A+", "B+", "O+", "AB+", "A-", "B-", "O-", "AB-"]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$bloodgroup",
      "total": {"$sum": "$ml"}
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "A+",
    "total": 2473
  },
  {
    "_id": "A-",
    "total": 3322
  },
  {
    "_id": "AB+",
    "total": 3635
  },
  {
    "_id": "AB-",
    "total": 3832
  },
  {
    "_id": "B+",
    "total": 1616
  },
  {
    "_id": "B-",
    "total": 1613
  },
  {
    "_id": "O+",
    "total": 4349
  },
  {
    "_id": "O-",
    "total": 2614
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r712l4g_Myr).

Comment: I will try for sure 

Comment: Hey I have another problem relating to this question can I ask?

Comment: @Digen If you have a new problem/question, it's best to write a new question rather than continuing here.